# unity3d не проходит сквозь объекты

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d

Добрый день.

У меня есть моделька и скрипт перемещающий ее вперед (методом `transform.Translate`). Проблема в том, что он проходит сквозь другие объекты (препятствия). На модели есть `box` и `mesh` коллайдер, ригидбoди. Если переместить скрипт на примитив (куб), то все выполняется как надо. На препятствиях есть тоже ригидбади, `box/mesh` коллайдер.

Подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

скрин модели

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[сам проект](http://dropmefiles.com/GmWI2/)

Comment: Прикрепи скрины компонентов на препятствии и на объекте.

Comment: @ValeraKvip Есть

Comment: А скрин на модельке? Я так понял примитив который на скрине работает как надо!?

Comment: попробуй у ригитбоди изменить режим детекта коллайдера с дискретного.на Continuous Dynamic. Если сработает - отпишись.

Comment: @ValeraKvip да,на кубе все нормально. http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=5ee542f2dc04d2b6043d048b9dae1f15 - скрин модели.Character Controller отключил,ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Andrew с измененным режимом ничего не изменилось(

Comment: @ValeraKvip в описании вставил ссылку на проект

Comment: @Andrew в описании вставил ссылку на проект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в этой строке:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
{
    Physics.IgnoreCollision (collision.collider, GetComponent<Collider>());
}
```

Не знаю цель этого, но эта функция блокирует все коллизии. А также Mesh Collider который тоже ведет себя странно.  В твоем персонаже ты что то натворил, не было времени разбираться что, я его удалил и создал заново(см скрин). И все работает. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ооо,спасибо большое!Без меш колайдера все заработало))